# How do I generate NPCs in PCGen?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, pcgen

I have found [a pretty handy website that could generate characters for D&D 3.0](http://www.hailscape.com/), but now I'm trying to run Pathfinder and I'm using PCGen, but I think the function I'm looking for is absent from my version. This is [how it's supposed to look](http://www.pcgen.org/autobuilds/pcgen-docs/menupages/file/filenpcgennpccreation.html):

[image: http://www.pcgen.org/autobuilds/pcgen-docs/images/windows/npc_generator.png]

However, my version of PCGen has only the following options in the file menu:

[image]

And so I'm not able to find it, even though I think my program has the resources to run a generation like that, as noted by its folder structure:

[image]

How do I launch this mode in PCGen?

Comment: Have you tried asking on the PCGen forum?  I've found them to be very responsive in the past.

Comment: To be honest, firstly I couldn't find the forums, and dismissed that they even had one.

Now that I have dug it out, I'm posting there, and I'll answer my own question.

Comment: So, to be clear...you're wanting PCGen to randomly generate an NPC, rather than just build one?

Comment: Yes, just like Hailscape does.

Comment: I see you got an answer.  Why don't you turn it into an answer here?

Comment: Yes, I'll do it as soon as I have time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### You don't

So, I created a [topic on the PCGen forums](http://groups.pcgen.org/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=493) to see if they could help me.

The answer was simple: The module was taken out of the software, but not entirely, for the lack of updates by the person that made it, who is now away from the project.

So, what I would suggest to everyone that has a similar wish to generate NPCs is:

1) Generate a 3.5 character at [MythWeavers NPC generator](http://www.myth-weavers.com/generate_npc.php)

2) Adjust what is missing, like feats and equipment.

This can help, at least while I don't have the time to create the tool myself (I'll keep this question as a promise to myself now).